# Getting 'MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota' error while trying to filter the process histories

Tags: wcf, tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to loop through all the items under **Workflow Management --> Process Histories** and do something.

The below is my code:

```cs
ProcessesFilterData filter = new ProcessesFilterData()
{
    BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.IdAndTitle,
    ProcessType = ProcessType.Historical
};
foreach (IdentifiableObjectData data in csClient.GetSystemWideList(filter))
{
     //doing somethine here
}
```

I am getting the below error in the line **foreach (IdentifiableObjectData data in csClient.GetSystemWideList(filter))**

**Error Message:**

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011:GetSystemWideListResult. The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'. Change the object graph or increase the MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota. '.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Comment: Change the maximum size for it. Use google to find out how, this is a WCF configuration issue, nothing to do with Tridion.

Comment: Not the same issue, but worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983114/how-should-i-decide-the-quotas-for-the-tridion-core-service-binding

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476853/wcf-error-maximum-number-of-items-that-can-be-serialized-or-deserialized-in-an

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out http://www.dailycode.info/Blog/post/2011/05/27/Change-the-object-graph-or-increase-the-MaxItemsInObjectGraph-quota.aspx. You can change the value in the Web.config in %TRIDION_HOME%\webservices. My installation alreaady has a value significantly higher than indicated by your error.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, when i checked my config file, it doesnt have endpointbehaviour node. it has only service behaviours node and its maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" is already set

Comment: Then I guess you need to find the web.config for your client and add/update the endpointbehaviour node value. How are you creating your CoreServe client?

Comment: var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647, ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas { MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647, MaxArrayLength = 2147483647 } }; I am using the above line when i create client

Comment: Look for the section called "Serialization behaviours" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732038.aspx

Comment: Incidentally, I found all of this information in a matter of minutes using Google and some, or all, of your error message as my search term...